# How do i prevent my android layout from turning horizontal/landscape when the device is being held horizontally

Tags: java, android, android-layout

In my android studio application my layout and design looks good and everything like i want it to when the device is being held vertically/portrait and I want it to stay like that when the app is being held horizontal/landscape so it stays as facing vertically. So how do I prevent the app from turning horizontal/landscape when the user turns the device horizontally so the layout is constantly facing vertically/portrait.

Comment: *"...and I want it to stay like that when the app is being held horizontal/landscape so it stays as facing vertically."* *Why*? Shouldn't the user be in control? This is like 960px websites. It's not up to the website to say how wide my browser window should be; that's ***my*** call.

Comment: there could be a few instances where you dont want the screen to rotate i.e. if you have no text and you are using the screen as a board. It might not be ideal, but as a user i can think of some cases where i wouldn't mind or even want to rotate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in the manifest file add to your activity:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```